# Question in Proof of Proposition 3.16 in A&M

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Proposition 3.16. Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is the contraction of a prime ideal of $B$ if and only if $\mathfrak{p}^{ec} = \mathfrak{p}$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $S$ be the image of $A-\mathfrak{p}$ in $B$. Then $\mathfrak{p}^e$ does not meet $S$, therefore by $(3,11)$ its extension in $S^{-1}B$ is a proper ideal and hence is contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $S^{-1}B$. If $\mathfrak{q}$ is the contraction of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $B$, then $\mathfrak{q}$ is prime, $\mathfrak{q}\supseteq \mathfrak{p}^e$ and $\mathfrak{q}\cap S=\emptyset$. Hence, $\mathfrak{q}^c = \mathfrak{p}$.

In the last part, why $\mathfrak{q}^c\subset\mathfrak{p}$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ denote the map $A\to B$. If $x\in {\frak q}^c\setminus {\frak p}$, then $f(x)\in {\frak q}$ and $f(x)\in f(A\setminus {\frak p})=S$ which contradicts ${\frak q}\cap S=\emptyset$.